# How to get entries to cache manifest file

Tags: html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm quite new to cache manifest and appcache in particular. From what I understood, cache manifest is a file which lists those to be stored on the cache for offline use, correct? Whenever you visit a new page, the page itself and its resources will be stored on appcache and will be added on the cache manifest file. Is there an event handler when there is a new entry on the cache manifest and if possible get the value of these new entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isnt. You have no programmatic access to the file.

Comment: I got the feeling that's the case. :( thanks though!